# DNS resolution fails after 12.10 upgrade

Tags: networking, 12.10, dns

After my upgrade to 12.10, DNS resolution seems to fail for both local and external addresses.  I can successfully ping local and external IP addresses (google.com, at least), but pinging DNS names immediately returns `ping: unknown host <hostname>`.  Connection Information seems to list the correct DNS servers (which I can ping successfully), and changing to Google Public DNS produces similar results.  What should I fuss with to try to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change 127.0.0.1 to 127.0.1.1 in `/etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: It looks like that worked.  I was under the impression resolv.conf is generated automatically.  This edit isn't going to get wiped out some day, is it?

Comment: That is going to get wiped out on reboot.

Comment: Yeah not a good solution.

Comment: `dpkg-reconfigure bind9-host` reboot.

Comment: If you have resolvconf installed then you should not edit /etc/resolv.conf, and if you do edit /etc/resolv.conf your edits will get overwritten. But if you have resolvconf installed then you don't have the problem in the first place, because NetworkManager registers the correct address, 127.0.1.1, with resolvconf which writes it into resolv.conf.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a known issue:

[Launchpad bug#1051348](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1051348)

The instructions there worked for me

Answer (score 1):

In a terminal,  run

```
sudo apt-get install resolvconf # in case it got removed
sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf # to restore the symlink at /etc/resolv.conf
```

then reboot.