# Cannot Ping from server when logged in from another machine

Tags: ssh, ping

So I found out my problem when I would use the curl method on my linux Ubunutu 12.10 Server at home while logged in from my laptop (Mac OSX Lion). Nothing was happening when I would use the curl method so I thought I would try to ping a website where I know its up and running and I would get this:

```
ping: unknown host facebook.com
```

So Im guessing there is something blocking something here. I tried other sites with no success. Just the same error. I researched elsewhere but I couldn't really find a solution.

I typed this in terminal:

```
sudo iptables -L
```

...and I got this response

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Does that look fine to anybody or should there be more information in there?

**Update**

I should also add that I am pretty new to hosting my own server and I have a Dynamic IP at the moment and not a static one. I have learned a lot over the past short while but just want to give the heads up that I may not know a whole lot about it.

That being said everyone seems to think its a DNS issue. So I checked the etc/resolv.conf file and there wasn't anything in there except a commented message.

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
```

Did I forget a step when setting up my server? Also would this fix the curl issues I was having. I was just trying to install RVM by curl according to the tutorial but nothing happened. No message that it failed or succeeded.

**Update 2**

<strike>So I did some research and it looks like a known bug with Ubuntu 12.10 upgrade, which I had just did before using these commands.</strike>

[DNS resolution fails after 12.10 upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/203044/dns-resolution-fails-after-12-10-upgrade)

*I thought the above was causing the problem but it wasn't in my case*

Here is what reads inside /etc/network/interfaces

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.131
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
```

Thanks,

Joe

Comment: That your /etc/resolv.conf file is empty suggests you're not getting the full DNS information from your router (or that you have somehow installed a dns server package on your Ubuntu machine that is taking precedence.)  What does this command say? `cat /etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: That seems to be the issue.  I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreed, this is a DNS resolution error.  You can verify this by pinging facebooks actual IP:

```
# ping 173.252.110.27
# 64 bytes from 173.252.110.27: icmp_seq=0 ttl=239 time=124.665 ms
# 64 bytes from 173.252.110.27: icmp_seq=1 ttl=239 time=83.031 ms
```

If pinging the IP fails, it's likely a network issue.  If it succeeds, it's likely a dns issue.

### UPDATE

Based on new information:

I'll assume (and if I'm wrong, I'll need to know a lot more about your setup) that you have a typical broadband internet service provider, and a typical consumer grade router that your other machines connect to just fine. If that is the case, you should comment out the last 5 lines and add this at the end:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Then perform these commands:

```
# sudo ifconfig eth0 down ; sudo ifconfig eth0 up ; sudo dhclient
```

Let me know if anything errors out.

Comment: Thanks, It seems like it is a DNS issue. Do you know how to fix the DNS issue or at least lead me in the right track. If you need more info I can provide it to you by testing and updating my question.

Comment: I will have to get back to you on that when I get home. These commands I will have to do on my server. Also whats with all the down votes? Should I reword some things? Also does would this affect curl as well? I can rewrite my question if it does.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Both using ping and curl are working normally.  I had a feeling it was something stupid like that.

Answer (score 2):

This is a name resolution error, not a ping error, per se.  Check that your DNS is configured properly (`/etc/resolv.conf`)

Comment: to add steps: try pinging 4.2.2.2 or 8.8.8.8.  If they resolve, definitely a DNS name resolution issue.

Comment: @TheCleaner yes that works. I also updated my question too.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `dns-nameservers` option in the `iface eth0 inet static` stanza of /etc/network/interfaces. The argument of this option should be the IP address of some nameserver. After adding this option, do `ifdown eth0 ; ifup eth0`.

Also make sure that the resolvconf package is installed and that /etc/resolv.conf is a symbolic link to `../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`; if it isn't, run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf`.